# PDO Select Statement returns nothing (FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to retrieve records from the mySQL-database but nothing gets selected. I'm using the below php function:

```
function printButton($conn){
$your_variable = 1;
$knappar = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM knappar WHERE pid  < :parameter');
$knappar->bindParam(':parameter', $your_variable, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$knappar->execute();

            //Loops boxes
          $count = 1;
          while ($row = $knappar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<a href='#'><div class='box' id='div_item".$count."'>";
            echo $row['header'];
            echo $row['id'];

            echo "</div></a>";
            $count = $count + 1;
            }

}
```

It works fine if I change "WHERE pid = 1" instead of the "< :parameter". What am I doing wrong?

I updated it to what it looks like now:

```
function printButton($conn){
$your_variable = 1;
$knappar = $conn->prepare('SELECT header FROM knappar WHERE pid < :parameter');
$knappar->bindParam(':parameter', $your_variable, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$knappar->execute();

            //Loops boxes
      $results = $knappar -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      foreach ($results as $row){

      echo $row['header'];
      echo '<br />';

      }

}
```

With above example, still no output. pid value is int(11) in the database and the value of all rows are 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$knappar -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) only fetches the next row of the result set. Use fetchAll to get the entire result set.

You could then iterate through the returned array with a foreach.

Granted, I'm not sure why it returns nothing rather than just the first row but give it a try.

Comment: `while ($row = $knappar->fetchALL)` still returns nothing.

Comment: A while loop isn't going to iterate through each result unless you manually do so (which you aren't).

`foreach (($knappar -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) as $row){
    //your code
}`

Comment: thanks, I'm getting another error now. _Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in_

Comment: Whoops, that's my mistake. Try declaring the results as a variable (eg `$results = $knappar -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`) and then use that in the foreach: `foreach ($results as $row)`

Comment: This one's just a typo. You want `WHERE pid < :parameter`, not `WHERE < :parameter`.

It's always the little things. :)

Comment: Well then I'm afraid I'm all out of ideas. I see no reason why it shouldn't work with fetchAll(). Sorry!

Comment: Just one more little question, why cant I use `WHERE = :parameter`? what does the "<" mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17751/discussion-between-albin-n-and-adamlazaruso)

Comment: "<" means less than... Or am I wildly misinterpreting that question? Suddenly it occurs to me that the problem might not be your code but the fact that you're looking for rows with ids that are less than 1 (which I doubt you have in your database).

Comment: Exactly, so what should I write to get `equal to 1` instead of `< 1`

Comment: Holy crap, I honestly believed that didn't work. Because I tried it before. Anyways. thanks man! sometimes you just need someone to talk to :)

Comment: No problem. I guess you didn't need fetchAll after all. I'm not sure where I got the idea that you were expecting multiple results, but I guess it's good for you to know for future reference anyway.